# Как заменить ID столбца на его название?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня сейчас хранится в веб-приложении ID столбца

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сделать, чтобы они заменялись на соответствующее название в другой таблице, то есть, в строке Программист баз данных ID деятельности было не число, а Коммерческое предприятие, а в строке Инженер газопровода было не ID, а Производственные предприятия.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется вот такой код:

Для таблицы с работой:

```
 <?php
$rabota = mysqli_query($connect, query:"SELECT * FROM `rabota`");
$rabota = mysqli_fetch_all($rabota);
foreach ($rabota as $rabota) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $rabota[1] ?></td>
        <td><?= $rabota[2] ?></td>
        <td><a href="deyatel.php"><?= $rabota[3] ?></a></td>
        <td><a href="dolgnost.php"><?= $rabota[4] ?></a></td>
        <td><a href="obrazov.php"><?= $rabota[5] ?></a></td>
        <td><a href="kval.php"><?= $rabota[6] ?></a></td>
        <td><a href="clientrabota.php"><?= $rabota[7] ?></a></td>
        <td><a href="../rabota_func/update_rabota.php?id=<?= $rabota[0] ?>">Изменить</a></td>
        <td><a style ="color: red;" href="../rabota_func/delete.php?id=<?= $rabota[0] ?>">Удалить</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Для таблицы с деятельностью:

```
    <tr>
        <td><?= $deyatel[1] ?></td>
        <td><a href="../deyatel_func/update_deyatel.php?id=<?= $deyatel[0] ?>">Изменить</a></td>
        <td><a style ="color: red;" href="../deyatel_func/delete.php?id=<?= $deyatel[0] ?>">Удалить</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: почитайте про left join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если предположить что таблица "Деятельность" в вашей базе данных имеет имя `activity` и в ней есть два поля `id и name`, а название поля "ID деятельности" в таблице `rabota` имеет имя `activity_id`, то вам нужно запрос `SELECT * FROM rabota` модифицировать так:

```
SELECT r.*, a.name 
FROM rabota r
LEFT JOIN activity a ON r.activity_id = a.id
```

и в своем html коде скорректировать индексы в массиве `$rabota`

Про связывание таблиц можно почитать тут https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает!